# Binding hotkey for toggling wireless card state - System76 Bonp3

Tags: wireless, shortcut-keys, hardware

Recently, my wireless card shut off on my laptop (System76 Bonp3 running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS). Awhile back, my keyboard had a meeting with a cup of coffee, and my F11 key no longer works. The key binding for turning my card back on happens to be Fn + F11, so I cannot turn my wifi on.

The only solution I can think of is to somehow change this to be bound to another key. I'm looking for the script that handles this particular hardware switch so I can bind it elsewhere.

Comment: I was unable to find this script, so I made my own: http://askubuntu.com/questions/240515

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Fn+Fx key bindings are controlled by the BIOS and not something that can be changed in the Ubuntu side of things. Go ahead and open a support ticket at the [System76 My Account Page](https://system76.com/my-account). We may be able to get you a new keyboard for your Bonobo.